# Request for the permission of type 'System.Web.AspNetHostingPermission failed

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

Full error:

```
Request for the permission of type 'System.Web.AspNetHostingPermission, System,
Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.
```

I'm doing maintenance on an old ASP.NET 2.0 "Web Site" project and am having issues with the error message posted in the topic. The reason for the error is that I recently enabled folder redirection on my account, and that all my files are now located on a network share.

I am aware of the trust issues with .NET applications, and as such used the .NET 2.0 Configuration Tool in Administrative Tools to set my Intranet trust level to Full. This had no effect. The problem seems to lie in the applications reference to ELMAH. When I compile the application and get the mentioned error, the source of the error is:

```
<add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah"/>
```

If I remove all references to ELMAH, the application behaves as expected, with no errors about trust levels. Can anyone enlighten me as to what's going on, and if there is a way to fix it? I assume this problem would be with any referenced DLL, not just ELMAH.

Also, I attempted to grant full access again via caspool, using the following:

```
Drive:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\caspol.exe -m -ag 1 -url
"file:////\\myserver\homeshare$\myusername\*" FullTrust -exclusive on
```

to no effect.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did:

```
C:\Windows\System32>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\caspol.exe –m -ag 1 -url "http://localhost/*" FullTrust
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check your .Net configuration trust settings, as mine were for some reason set to NONE. I changed the assembly trust back to Full Trust and it solved my problem.

Check at @Pepepe's answer in this thread:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1116931.aspx?Ajax+Request+for+the+permission+of+type+System+Web+AspNetHostingPermission+System